# combine list of dictionaries with same key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to combine a list of dictionaries with the same key. The result I am going for is a list of dictionaries with unique "Org_ID". All "Range" for same "Org_ID" would be in a single dict within the list. Here is my original data:

```
orig_data = [{'Range': '192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, 
             {'Range': '192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, 
             {'Range': '192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, 
             {'Range': '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, 
             {'Range': '192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254', 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, 
             {'Range': '10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254', 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, 
             {'Range': '172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}, 
             {'Range': '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}]
```

What I am going for:

```
new_data = [{'Range': ['192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254','192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254','192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254','10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254'] 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, 
            {'Range': ['192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254','10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254'] 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, 
            {'Range': ['172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254','172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254'] 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}]
```

I was trying to do it using this:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for i in (orig_data):
  for elem in orig_data:
    d[elem['Org_ID']].update(elem)
new_data = d.values()
```

But then "new_data" only contains a single dictionary.

I have also tried doing it with this:

```
new_data = dict([(k, [orig_data[k]]) for k in orig_data])
```

But that is not working either. I assume because its looking for a single dict and not a list of dicts?

Comment: Looks like you need `ipcalc` module to help you evaluate those strings used in the `dict`s' values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orig_data = [{'Range': '192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254', 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, {'Range': '10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254', 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, {'Range': '172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}, {'Range': '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}]

cont = collections.defaultdict(lambda : collections.defaultdict(list))
for d in orig_data:
    cont[d['Org_ID']][d['name']].append(d['Range'])

answer = []
for orgid in cont:
    for name,rangelist in cont[orgid].items():
        answer.append({'Org_ID':orgid, 'name':name, 'Range':rangelist})
```

Output:

```
In [226]: answer
Out[226]: 
[{'name': 'TX-Houston',
  'Org_ID': 'TX',
  'Range': ['172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254']},
 {'name': 'TX-Dallas',
  'Org_ID': 'TX',
  'Range': ['192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254',
   '192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254',
   '192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254',
   '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254']},
 {'name': 'CA-San Diego',
  'Org_ID': 'CA',
  'Range': ['192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254', '10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254']}]
```

Comment: What would I need to change if I dont want the 'Range' in each dict to be a list? Meaning all of the data would remain, it just would not be a list.

Comment: You could use a `set` (you'll lose any duplicates, for which you might then want to use a `collections.Counter`). But ultimately, you'll need a collection of some sort. Why are you averse to using a list?

Comment: I tried set and that doesnt work either. The reason is that the code that is accepting this data is expecting input like '172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254' for the 'Range' and not a list.

Comment: Make a new post with the code that reads Range (which is currently a list), and we'll help you out further. Right now, I'm not 100% sure what you mean, and I have a feeling that explaining it will require about as much space for a brand new post

Answer (score 1):

```
orig_data = [{'Range': '192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}, {'Range': '192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254', 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, {'Range': '10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254', 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}, {'Range': '172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}, {'Range': '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254', 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'}]

from collections import defaultdict

from itertools import groupby

res = []
for key, vals in groupby(orig_data, lambda x: (x["Org_ID"], x["name"])):
    res.append(defaultdict(list))
    for d in vals:
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            if k == "Range":
                res[-1][k].append(v)
            else:
                res[-1][k] = v
[defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Range': ['192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254', '192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254', '192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254', '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254'], 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Dallas'}),
 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Range': ['192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254', '10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254'], 'Org_ID': 'CA', 'name': 'CA-San Diego'}),
 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Range': ['172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254'], 'Org_ID': 'TX', 'name': 'TX-Houston'})]
```

if you want to hardcode the keys you can shorten the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

from itertools import groupby

res = []
for key, vals in groupby(orig_data, lambda x: (x["Org_ID"], x["name"])):
    res.append(defaultdict(list))
    for d in vals:
        res[-1]["Range"].append(d["Range"])
    res[-1]['Org_ID'] = d['Org_ID']
    res[-1]["name"] = d["name"]
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley, made a mistake I think though op wants a list of dicts!

Comment: ahh I see ... oh well

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_data = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for entry in orig_data:
    key = (entry["Org_ID"], entry["name"])
    new_data[key].append(entry["Range"])

res = [{"Org_ID":k[0], "name":k[1], "Range":v} for k,v in new_data.items()]
```

So that:

```
>>> res
[{'Org_ID': 'TX',
  'Range': ['172.16.0.1-172.16.0.254', '172.16.3.1-172.16.3.254'],
  'name': 'TX-Houston'},
 {'Org_ID': 'CA',
  'Range': ['192.168.9.1-192.168.1.254', '10.0.5.1-10.0.5.254'],
  'name': 'CA-San Diego'},
 {'Org_ID': 'TX',
  'Range': ['192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254',
   '192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254',
   '192.168.3.1-192.168.3.254',
   '10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254'],
  'name': 'TX-Dallas'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
keys = ('Org_ID', 'name', 'Range')
new_data = {}

for d in orig_data:
    o, n, r = (d[k] for k in keys)
    if o not in new_data:
        new_data[o] = dict(zip(keys, (o, n, [r])))
    else:
        new_data[o]['Range'].append(r)

new_data = list(new_data.values())
```